# How to integrate Qt into an existing application development workflow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, mfc

I have been playing with Qt for a week or so, with the aim of integrating Qt dialogs into an existing application. I've figured out use a basic Qt Message box from my MFC application, eg:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool showDialog( HWND parent )
{
    QWinWidget win( parent );
    win.showCentered();
    QMessageBox::about( &win, "About QtMfc", "QtMfc Version 1.0\nCopyright (C) 2003" );

    return TRUE;
}
```

I've used Qt Designer to create dialog boxes. What I haven't figured out is how to bring all of these pieces together. Qt Designer leaves me with a .ui file. I've seen that I can use uic to compile that to a .h file, but where are the other parts, like .cpp files? Further, if I want to compile the Qt parts to a dll, which are loaded on demand, what is the process for that? To put it into context, the existing application has 1000's of dialogs that the user may want to use, hence they all live in dll's that are loaded as needed and the dialogs come as additional downloads, kind of a plugin if you will, separately from the main program.

This is probably missing a lot, so please bring on the questions.

thanks,
Daniel

Comment: to clarify, I'm not looking for an "answer" as much as links to existing resources for this. If you have "the answer", that is great, but I don't really expect that...

Answer (score 1):

Get the [VS plugin](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in), it makes Qt work seamlessly with VS.

It complies ui files into classes which you then call from your code. You can also write dialogs, menus, etc in your C code. Since it uses sizers for layout there isn't a lot of X-Y coords to manage to place every component.

Although if you can I would go for a big-bang approach of replacing the MFC main with a Qt main and moving the functionality over. AFAIK MFC dialogs should work perfectly well in a Qt app.

Comment: the application is a 30+ man-years effort. Complete redo is not an option, as of now, but we're hoping to get it there ;-)

Comment: I'm playing with the VS plugin now. You have any good links to Qt docs on this stuff? I've been through a lot of them and still don't feel like I have what I need. Still just playing with stuff and *hoping* to find the "ah ha" point...

Comment: Very interesting issue.I would like to know the answer as well.

Comment: while I do enjoy working in Visual Studio, I like to know what is going on under the covers. I went to the library, of all places... ;-), and found two books that cover those "under the covers" details. Those books are: "Qt 4: The Art of Building Qt Applications" by Daniel Molkentin and "Foundations of Qt Development" by Johan Thelin. I'll do a blog post of my findings and post a link back to it here.